# Automatically Update Page in Browser when Changes are Made in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Okay I may be crazy, but I could swear that I have seen webpages being worked on in Visual Studio update when changes are made and the file is save the file. NO manual page refresh.

These were not changes made through the debugger. Made in Visual Studio.

Is there something that does that and if so what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saw result of [Browser Link](http://webtooling.visualstudio.com/project-system/browser-link/) work. Nothing else can do so

Comment: That looks and sounds like it, but for some reason it doesn't work all the time. The page you linked isn't completely clear on the limitations, but you gave me a place to start researching. Thanks!